# How to export the cell that contains new line character properly?

Tags: openrefine

I have a row of data as below. The problem is that it will be exported as three rows in `csv` file; how do I export it as one row?

```
    ________________________________________________________________________________________
    |id              |exception
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |cell_1_content  |hash*app_version*..is not enabled.
    |                |   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2982)
    |                |   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3025)
    |                |   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:123)
     _______________________________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you send a short sample of your real worksheet ?

But if your Open refine project looks like this (screenshot), you can gather cells "exception" in one with this Grel Formula (column "exception", add column based on this column):

```
row.record.cells["exception"].value.join (" ")
```

Then, facet column "ID" by _blank, click on "true" and "remove all matching rows".

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AacKQ.jpg)